# How to bring the mail composer view in between the view and tool bar in iphone?

Tags: iphone, email, toolbar

I am new to iphone development.I want a toolbar and a button in it.On clicking the button ,a mail compose view should open.I want the tool bar to be visible in the mail composer view.The mail composer should animate from back of the toolbar.How can i achieve that.

Recently i saw a application,which implemented this.The mail emerges from back of the tool bar.

In general which is more preferable for creating application like m need.Tabar or tool bar? any other method should i follow?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally Solved it.

I am able to get a button  above the mail composer view by setting the button to the window. So that button is display above the mail composer view.

Answer (score 0):

I think, that the MailComposer view is always a model view and therefore you can't make your toolbar visible. Also the mailcomposer view has got it's own toolbar.

Look here for further information:
http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/MessageUI/Reference/MFMailComposeViewController_class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: I have seen a application working like this.But i am not sure about that it was a tool bar.They had five icons as a tab bar but it as a click event and mail view emerges from the background and not hiding the bar.

Comment: What was the application called?

Comment: @ jasarien University of Nebraska. its free in app store

Comment: do you mean that mail composer, if you tap on "share" in the tabbar?

Comment: yes pal.How could i achieve that.Are you sure its tabbar.I can see a click event firing.

Comment: it looks like a tabbar but i don't think it's a UITabBar. the mail composer view could also be from the three-20 framework by joe hewitt (the one who made the facebook app). it's available free.

here you get further information:
http://joehewitt.com/post/the-three20-project/